# error: addinfo_cache failed while cherrypicking

Tags: gerrit, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I am getting the followinge error while cherry-picking a gerrit...does anyone have info on what this means and why would anyone see it?

```
error: addinfo_cache failed for path 'ROE/NAS/src/abc.c
```

Comment: A bit of googling indicates that this is a bug, however I don't know where to find more information about it. I seem to experience this issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this has something to do with the whitespace and EOL. I also got the same issue today and just used the `git-->mergetool` to resolve the issue based on the following thread - http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/error-addinfo-cache-failed-during-merge-tp6840473p6840622.html.

The only cause of concern, I now see the entire file modified instead of just the two lines which were part of my cherry-pick changeset.

Answer (score -3):

Run `git stash` before cherry-picking. It helped at least in my case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: change the answer from question-like to a (real) answer

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer. However, it still looks more like a comment than an answer. The "try" indicates that you are not sure whether your suggestion is a solution to the OP's problem. I think it would be better if you could at least explain, why _git stash_ might solve the problem.

Comment: Well, I have answered it over a year ago, so I can't remember the detailed rationale. As far as I remember it simply helped me in a similar case. I believe the current aswer is ok, feel free to downvote it if you don't like it.

Comment: I posted my first comment while reviewing posts in the low-qualtiy queue, because your answer showed up there. As you responded, I wanted to motivate you to improve your answer. It looks a bit better now and I think it no longer deserves a down-vote. Thank you for your effort!